# Find my mistake: Prove $\sum_{i=0}^{r} \sum_{j=0}^{c} \binom{i+j}{j}=\binom{r+c+2}{c+1}-1$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I want to prove $\sum_{i=0}^{r} \sum_{j=0}^{c} \binom{i+j}{j}=\binom{r+c+2}{c+1}-1$, but the result is different. What is wrong?

$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{i=0}^{r} \sum_{j=0}^{c} \binom{i+j}{j}\\
=&\sum_{i=0}^{r} \sum_{j=0}^{c} [x^j]\frac{1}{(1-x)^{i-1}} \\
=&\sum_{j=0}^{c} [x^{j}]  \frac{1-\frac{1}{(1-x)^{r}}}{x} \\
=&[x^{c}]  \frac{\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{(1-x)^{r+1}}}{x} \\
=&\binom{r+c+2}{c+1}\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a proof using coefficient extractors is desired we may proceed as
follows:

$$\sum_{p=0}^n \sum_{q=0}^m {p+q\choose q}
= \sum_{p=0}^n \sum_{q\ge 0} {p+q\choose q} [[0\le q\le m]]
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^n \sum_{q\ge 0} {p+q\choose q} [z^m] \frac{z^q}{1-z}
= [z^m] \frac{1}{1-z}
\sum_{p=0}^n \sum_{q\ge 0} {p+q\choose q} z^q
\\ = [z^m] \frac{1}{1-z}
\sum_{p=0}^n \frac{1}{(1-z)^{p+1}}
= [z^m] \frac{1}{(1-z)^2}
\sum_{p=0}^n \frac{1}{(1-z)^{p}}
\\ = [z^m] \frac{1}{(1-z)^2}
\frac{1/(1-z)^{n+1}-1}{1/(1-z)-1}
= [z^m] \frac{1}{1-z}
\frac{1/(1-z)^{n+1}-1}{z}
\\ = [z^{m+1}] \frac{1}{1-z}
(1/(1-z)^{n+1}-1)
= -1 + [z^{m+1}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+2}}
\\ = -1 + {m+1+n+1\choose n+1}.$$

This is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
-1 + {m+n+2\choose n+1}}$$

as claimed.

Answer (score 0):

In this sort of calculation, it’s usually a good idea to look for the simplest example and check each step using it. In the present case, the simplest example is $r=c=0$. Going through the steps in the displayed equations, you can see that the value is $1$ in the first line, still $1$ in the second line, but then $0$ in the third line. So there must actually be two mistakes, since in the last line the value is $2$.

I'm not sure how you arrived at the third line; I get

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{i=0}^r\frac1{(1-x)^{i-1}}
&=&
(1-x)\sum_{i=0}^r\frac1{(1-x)^i}
\\
&=&
(1-x)\frac{1-\frac1{(1-x)^{r+1}}}{1-\frac1{1-x}}
\\
&=&
-(1-x)^2\frac{1-\frac1{(1-x)^{r+1}}}x\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

Here's a direct proof:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{r} \sum_{j=0}^{c} \binom{i+j}{j}
&=\sum_{i=0}^{r} \sum_{j=0}^{c} \binom{i+j}{i}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{r} \binom{i+c+1}{i+1}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{r} \binom{i+c+1}{c}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{r+1} \binom{i+c}{c}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{r+1} \binom{i+c}{c}-\binom{0+c}{c}\\
&=\binom{r+c+2}{c+1}-1
\end{align}